# Redirect URL without change domain

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have one server with IP address (say) `w.x.y.z`, and 2 domains parked on it.

```
mydomain.com

herdomain.com
```

I also have 3 file manager (php autoindex free) like this:

```
mydomain.com/Files/index.php?dir=folder1/folder2/

herdomain.com/myfiles/index.php?dir=mydata/folder2/
```

now I want to redirect users who open `folder2` (from one of the above urls) to this url without changing domain (is it possible)?

```
w.x.y.z/support/index.php?dir=mainfolder/folder2/
```

how can I do this on autoindex or `.htaccess` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in web root "/"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mydomain|heredomain)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dir=(folder1|mydata)/folder2/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://w.x.y.z/support/index.php?dir=mainfolder/folder2/ [L]
```

Comment: @PashaAleayoob Glad to help. +1 for the question.